# Estilos global com styled-components

Tags: react-native, styled-components

Como posso incrementar estilos globais em styled-components?

Tenho um arquivo com varias variáveis de estilos, como posso incrementar no styled-components?

**Exemplo:**

> src/styles/colors.js

```
const ColorPrimary = "#000"
```

> src/screens/login/styles.js

```
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

const Container = styled.View``
```

Como posso incrementar este ColorPrimary dentro do Container?

Comment: Como assim incrementar? Voce quer dizer usar dentro do estilo do `Container`?

Comment: Exatamente isso

Comment: Só passar como _template string_ não funciona? Algo como `color: ${ ColorPrimary }` dentro do `styled.view`.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que uma solução satisfatória seria criar um theme e usar no styles-components.

Então imagina que vc tem um theme assim

```
export default {
  colors: {
    primary: '#000',
  }
}
```

usando o tema do styled components, você vai pode acessar assim

```
import styled from 'styled-components/native'

export const Container = styled.View`
  background: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.primary;
`;
```

É bem legal essa abordagem, eu costumo adicionar algumas coisas bem uteis como, as cores, nome da família de fontes e o que mais achar necessário.

No final fica mais ou menos assim o meu :)

```
export default {
  colors: {
    primary: '#000',
  },
  font: {
    family: {
      black: 'Poppins-Black',
      blackItalic: 'Poppins-BlackItalic',
      bold: 'Poppins-Bold',
      boldItalic: 'Poppins-BoldItalic',
      extraBold: 'Poppins-ExtraBold',
   },
   metrics: {
     window: {
      width,
      height,
     },
     statusBarHeight: Platform.select({
       android: 0,
       ios: getStatusBarHeight(),
       default: 0,
     }),
     bottomSpace: Platform.select({
       android: 0,
       ios: getBottomSpace(),
       default: 0,
     }),
    }
  }
}
```